# Execute a namespaced function from within html onclick

Tags: javascript

How can I call a function which is namespaced within a variable from html

```
<button onclick="hello()">Click me</button>

var app  = app || {};
(function($) {
    app.hello = function() {
         console.log("hello");   
    }
})(app, jQuery);
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5XMYD/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<button onclick="app.hello()">Click me</button>
```

You need to select the `no wrap in <head>` or `no wrap in <body>` option in jsfiddle, or else your `app` variable will not have global scope and will not be accessible from your event handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/5XMYD/8/

With all that said, you should be using unobtrusive JavaScript, and not inline event handlers:

```
<button id="clickButton">Click me</button>

$(function() {
    $("#clickButton").click(app.hello);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5XMYD/9/

Answer (score 0):

simply doing this should work

```
<button onclick="app.hello()">Click me</button>
```

Though for some reason it does not work in jsfiddle. Working fine in real environment.

Comment: It doesn't work in jsfiddle because the "onLoad" option is selected.